# Можно ли закомментировать код внутри тега в xml?

Tags: xml

Можно ли закомментировать код внутри тега xml файла? Код не внутри тега возможно комментировать, но возможно ли комментировать код внутри тега? Так намного удобнее проверять функции.

```xml
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<!--        android:padding="16dp"-->
        android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Comment: Синтаксис XML такого не позволяет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандарт XML [не позволяет](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments) объявлять комментарии внутри блока открытия тега.

Я обычно делаю так: комментирую атрибут с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, далее вытаскиваю закомментированный атрибут за пределы тега с помощью <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>:

```xml
<!--        android:padding="16dp"-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Есть еще такой способ, может быть вам подойдет, объявить фейковый неймспейс `_android="http://"`, и заменять `android` на `_android`, чтобы «выключить» атрибут:

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:_android="http://"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        _android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</FrameLayout>
```